# How can I make tooltips stop popping up in Finder list view?

Tags: macos, finder

When I put a Finder window into list view, and the file name is too long to fit into the column width, the Finder pops up a yellow tooltip with the full name. The delay is too short and it gets in the way. I've found a way to disable tooltips in all Cocoa applications (or set the delay to long enough that it's not a bother) but not for the Finder. Does anyone know the secret command to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I have never seen an option to do this anywhere but you can give [Secrets](http://secrets.blacktree.com/) a try. If there is such an option this application will most definitely have it. A quick search of [MacOSXHints](http://www.macosxhints.com/) doesn't reveal anything but worth keeping an eye on as well.

Comment: On that note, I know there is definitely a setting to *increase the delay* for some popups, though I'm not sure about removing them entirely.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, if you hold the <kbd>option</kbd> key in the Finder it will cause tooltips to display immediately until you navigate away from the window which may be causing the short delay issue you're having (unless the 2-3 second delay is what you're having issues with)

Unfortunately there is no way to increase the delay of tooltips in the Finder.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to increase the delay.

- Open the terminal and type: `defaults write -g NSInitialToolTipDelay -int 10000`
- the value is passed in milliseconds

Click here for more [detailed instructions](http://www.macworld.com/article/1055202/termtooltips.html)

Comment: Perhaps you can add a summary of the link? Sometimes the relevant information disappears.